# Activating expression language in web.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jakarta-ee

[Eclipse IDE, JEE, Tomcat, Servlets, JSP with expression language, MVC pattern]
I'm doing some simple examples that should demonstrate MVC pattern - servlet controller forwarding requests to appropriate JSP pages, where I need to use expression language(in JSP pages).

To use expression language in JSP pages, i need to activate it in web.xml file, so i put these lines in web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
      version="3.0">
```

My question is: 
What exactly(generally) these lines represent? 
I know that this way expression language has been activated, but just asking for simple explanation how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a declaration of XML document where you say what namespace, schema and it's version you want to use in this document. It's then used by the validator to check whether is your document structure correct.

Answer (score 2):

It just means, the web application conforms to the servlet specification version 3 which contains EL.